# BCrypt password not matching when changed through Mutator Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.4, mutators

i got a Laravel 5.4 project where i'm trying to run a simple integration test which checks to see if the user can login properly, in order to do this i'm generating, a new user via a Factory.

```
    $user = factory(User::class)->create(['password' =>'secret']);
```

Then in my Test

```
    $this->visitRoute('admin.login')
         ->submitForm('LOGIN', ['email' => $user->email, 'password' => 'secret'])
         ->seeIsAuthenticated()
         ->seeStatusCode(200);
```

The user is never authenticated, i can confirm the $user->email matches the one in the DB, but the password never does...

So i checked the hash it generated in the DB with the "secret" string on this website https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator

I get an error saying `invalid salt revision` i'm puzzled, what is this all about?
I'm hashing the password via a Mutator, which looks like this

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

As per advice already given in one of the comments below i tried the following solution

```
    $hasher = new BcryptHasher();
    $hash = $hasher->make($value);

    $this->attributes['password'] = $hash;
```

Through xDebug i can tell that it enters the make() method twice, once on initialisation before the Mutator is called and it sends a random set of chars at this point, then it will run the mutator and the make() command with the string `secret` just as expected, i pull the Hash it generates and find the same issue... `invalid salt revision`

Comment: Looks like you're using the raw bcrypt() function there, but you may need to create an instance of the Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher and call $hasher->make($value) to create a hash that includes everything set in the Laravel environment

Comment: @markdwhite didn't work :(

Comment: If you're calling it through a mutator, do you think the ModelFactory will call that on creation? Maybe factory(User::class)->create(['password' => $alreadyHashedPassword])

Comment: @markdwhite i've ran it against xdebug and it did go to the Mutator... i don't understand, if i can't use mutators in ModelFactories than that would mean ModelFactories themselves are broken, what's the point of Factories if i can't use them like this?

Comment: I see your point, and I can see that the mutator would be called. Looks like you've got more information to look at after your last edit so I'll look out for updates.

Comment: @markdwhite i was mistaken, the reason for the random string was just that it calls the make() method twice, once before the mutator and again afterwards.
It's running with a cost of 10, i believe this is the default for BCrypt in Laravel correct?

Comment: Yes, it's 10 by default. I set it low for unit tests in TestCase (last comment here to avoid extended discussion)

Comment: I'm asking out of curiosity - why are you not using `password_hash` function to hash the password? What's the catch with this method of yours, why is it any good?

Answer (score 0):

I use this mutator in my User model and the password is hashed automatically only if it needs:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    if( \Hash::needsRehash($value) ) {
        $value = \Hash::make($value);
    }
    $this->attributes['password'] = $value;
}
```

Comment: nope, same problem, for instance for 'secret' it generated the following hash

`$2y$10$q05LuNs5TkLEvrLvv7.bx.26cRPdw1NXooGHUPvp7xPW/1AemmlJS`

Simply checking online tells me quickly that this hash is invalid for that string :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, it was silly, so, in my LoginController i was checking if the user has the active flag set along with the email and password matching...

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return Auth::attempt([
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
        'active' => 1
    ]);
}
```

Basically, my Factory has a 50/50 rule regarding the 'active' flag so anytime the generated user had the active flag = 1 it would work, the other 50% of the time it would fail.

Sorry but thanks for your help everyone, hope this helps someone in the future :)